# Adding A Filegroup To An Existing Partition Schema

Tags: sql-server-2008, partitioning

From BOL, I can see that the only way to ALTER a PARTITION SCHEME is to set the NEXT USED flag. This doesn't seem to add a new filegroup to the schema (or at least its not visible when I script out the schema as DROP/CREATE). Is it possible to add a new filegroup to an existing SCHEME or does this have to be done at initial creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using altering the scheme by using NEXT USED command and when I scripted the scheme the new FG was mentione in the script.

I think you might not have added any data which would reside in the new FG which is why it was not mentioned in the scheme script.

Here is the complete example.

Select *
from sys.filegroups 
go

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION myRangePF1 (int)
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1, 100, 1000);
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME myRangePS1
AS PARTITION myRangePF1
ALL TO ( [PRIMARY] );

CREATE TABLE test (col1 int primary key , col2 int )
on myRangePS1(col1)
go

Insert into test 
Select 2 , 1
union 
Select 20,2
union 
Select 200, 3
union 
Select 2000, 4

GO

ALTER PARTITION SCHEME MyRangePS1
NEXT USED [SECONDARY];

GO

ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION myRangePF1 ()
SPLIT RANGE (1500);

--Script the scheme
-- The second from last FG is Secondary 
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [myRangePS1] AS PARTITION [myRangePF1] TO ([PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [**Secondary**], [PRIMARY])
GO

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, I get the same problem with this as I did when testing, and that is that the schema cannot be altered or dropped/recreated.

On DELETE: The partition scheme "myRangePS1" is currently being used to partition one or more tables.

On ALTER: I get a syntax error because the only alter available is NEXT USED.

Comment: You are right...I just wasn't seeing this from the correct angle. Thanks!